# i want to show more photos in Same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

In my screen i have 3 buttons with 3 imageview to show the corresponding image picked from the UIImagepicker (from camera / Album). 
But once i selected the image it was displaying only last picked image to the uiimageview. Kindly give me the details where im making mistake.

Is it possible to fix the orientation to Landscape while we select the picture?

im using Objective c (iOS).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some sample code for us to review?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it by moving all of my code from viewDidLoad(), to viewDidAppear(). 
For example, if you had this:

```
@IBOutlet var image_view : UIImageView!
```

And set its .image property in viewDidLoad(),

```
image_view.image = my_picked_image
```

You should move this code to viewWillAppear().